# How to make a function file in Ocatve with multiple functions

Tags: octave

I know that you can make a function file in Octave in which the file name is the same as the function which defines one function, but I would like to define multiple functions in one file. Is there any way to do this, or do I need a separate file for each function.

Comment: there is, but it's not recommended. perhaps you might want to explain what problem you're trying to solve in this manner?

Comment: I just have a library of functions which I need to use for a variety of reasons, but I just find the need to make a separate file for each function tedious and I like to see the functions in one file because it makes it easier for editing and transporting.

Answer (score 5):

In this answer I will assume that your main objective is a tidy workspace rather than explicitly a one-file requirement.

Let's get the one-file approach out of the way. You can create a *script* m-file (not a function m-file), and define a number of [command-line functions](https://octave.org/doc/v5.2.0/Function-Precedence.html#Function-Precedence) there. The octave manual [has a section on this](http://octave.org/doc/v5.2.0/Script-Files.html#Script-Files). Here's an example:

```
% in file loadfunctionDefinitions.m
1;   % statement with side-effect, to mark this file as a script. See docs.
function Out = Return1(); Out = 1; end
function Out = Return2(); Out = 2; end
% ... etc
```

```
% in your main octave session / main script:
X = Return1() + Return2();
```

However, this is generally not recommended. Especially if you would require matlab compatible code, since matlab introduced 'script-local functions' *much* later than octave, and decided to do it in a manner incompatible to the existing octave implementation: matlab expects script-local functions to be defined at the end of the script; octave expects them to be defined before first use. However, if you use normal function files, everything is fine.

While I appreciate the "I don't like a folder full of functions" sentiment, the one-function-per-file approach actually has a lot of benefits (especially if you program from the terminal, which makes a wealth of tools twice as useful). E.g. you can easily use `grep` to find which functions make use of a particular variable. Or compare changes in individual functions from different commits, etc.

Typically the problem is more one of having such function files littering the directory, when other important files are present, e.g. data etc, and having so many files in one place makes finding what you want hard to spot, and feels untidy. But rather than have a single file with command-line definitions, there are a number of other approaches you can take, which are probably also better from a programmatic point of view, e.g.:

- Simply create a 'helper functions' folder, and add it to your path.
- Use subfunctions in your main functions whenever this is appropriate, to minimize the number of unnecessary files
- Use a private functions folder
- Use a ['package directory'](https://octave.org/doc/v5.2.0/Manipulating-the-Load-Path.html), i.e. a folder starting with the character '+', which creates a namespace for the functions contained inside. E.g. `~/+MyFunctions/myfun.m` would be accessed from `~/` via `MyFunctions.myfun()`, without having to add `+MyFunctions` to the path (in fact you're not supposed to).
- Create a proper [class directory](https://octave.org/doc/v5.2.0/Object-Oriented-Programming.html#Object-Oriented-Programming), and make your functions methods of that class

The last option may also achieve a one-file solution, if you use a newer-style `classdef` based class, which allows you to define methods in the same file as the class definition. Note however that octave-support for `classdef`-defined classes is [still somewhat limited](https://octave.org/doc/v5.2.0/classdef-Classes.html#classdef-Classes).

Comment: In your 1-file approach, does `Return1` know about `Return2`? Are those functions accessible from a 3rd function defined in another file? I’ve never used that approach, I’m curious about if.

Comment: @CrisLuengo yes, as long as everything is defined on the "workspace" at the time of their call, it's as if there's an m-file defined on the path. In fact if you try to `edit` that function, it will create such a file with the file definition copied in. I put "workspace" in quotes because they don't actually appear on the workspace like variables do. That's another one of my gripes with command-line functions, I do not know of a way to query at runtime (e.g. from the terminal) what functions have been defined.